# call page function from firefox addon with location.href doesn't work

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

i try to call a javascript function from the original page from my firefox extension content_script like this:

**content_scripts.js**

```
location.href="javascript:tellParent('lightboxClose();'); void 0";
```

This works very well in my Chrome Extension but doesn't work in my Firefox Addon.

Is there a similar solution or a workaround to call that function from the page?
I'm searching for a solution since hours and can't get it to work.

Hope you can help me

Comment: window.location.href

Comment: doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly after hours of searching i found a solution that works for me.

[Calling webpage JavaScript methods from browser extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40572065/calling-webpage-javascript-methods-from-browser-extension)